# Delorme GPS and Delorme X map alternatives

Tags: gps

We have a group doing field work and are having issues using Delorme GPS and Delorme X Map[image: Delorme GPS pn 40] and Delorme X Map.

Wondering if there is a way to connect the delorme GPS pn 40 to ArcReader / ArcExplorer in the field?

All shape files used in the field are polylines ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Please expand on what issues you are having? gps fixes? connectivity or mapping software...

Comment: user-friendliness is the main issue... the idea is to try it on ArcExplorer or ArcReader or whatever and just see if there are any better options.

Comment: It should work with Google Earth and ArcGIS Explorer - make sure you have the latest firmware - http://blog.delorme.com/2010/12/27/sneak-peak-earthmate-pn-6060w-3-2-firmware-update/

Comment: thanks Mapperz, please excuse my ignorance, but how do we download that firmware update? not seeing any download buttons on that link... also we are having the most basic problem of just trying to get the pn40 to connect to the laptop, i'm read thru the manual on "connect to computer" and implemented the instructions several times/ways but still cannot make it recognize the device ... any ideas ?

Comment: Which Operating System? Firmware BACKUP! first (SD CARD?) - firmware (2.8) http://support.delorme.com/questions.php?questionid=98 - Connect your PN-Series GPS to your PC using the USB cable. A new drive should appear attached to your computer.

Comment: Thanks again! the laptop has windows 7... not sure where / what sd card is... the link/download you provided gives us more things to try... i think the following is probably going to work: "Windows Manual Installation instructions

1. Before connecting your PN-Series GPS to your computer, activate Firmware Transfer mode.
a. Press the MENU button from any PN-Series GPS screen.
b. Select Device Setup.
c. Select Connect to Computer...
d. Open the USB Setting drop-down menu.
e. Select Firmware Transfer and stop there.

Note: If you see ....."

Comment: did this work for you?

Comment: sorry for the late reply... basically we determined delorme GPS pn 40 is not designed to do what we need... hopefully the company will be getting a nice Garmin GPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your GPS to a laptop running ArcReader using the following script.  Works at 9.3 but I haven't tested on 10.

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15506